# Ionic 2 Issue : No provider for Push

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ionic2

I have the following code in my Ionic 2 project which is suppose to receive Push Notifications. When I run the code I keep getting an error in the console saying No provider for Push.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ionicBootstrap, Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen} from 'ionic-native';
import { CloudSettings, PushToken, Push } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl:'build/app.html'
})

constructor(public platform: Platform, private userProvider: UserProvider, public push: Push) {const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
    'core': {
      'app_id': 'XXXXXXX',
    },
    'push': {
      'sender_id': 'XXXXXXX',
      'pluginConfig': {
        'android': {
          'iconColor': '#343434'
        }
      }
    }
  };

  this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
      return this.push.saveToken(t);
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
      console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
    });

  this.push.rx.notification()
    .subscribe((msg) => {
      alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
    });

});
```

I am thinking this is some kind of ionic 2 version mismatch here is my ionic info details below

```
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
OS: Distributor ID:     Ubuntu Description:     Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 
Node Version: v4.5.0
```

Comment: I would start by considering what the error message says, and check that I indeed have declared Push in my list of providers.

Comment: Post your NgModule

Comment: @JBNizet added it check my edits

Comment: No, you haven't. There is no NgModule anywhere in your question.

Comment: An Angular 2 application is a class decorated with `@NgModule( {...} )`. That's basically where you configure your app. Show that code.

Comment: It is not an angular app per se, it is an ionic 2 app built on angular 2 but does not quite implement all the features u can check out the git repo for this project https://github.com/kolexinfos/shoppa

Comment: And yet, the official instructions are pretty clear: http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html

Comment: Thanks I can that the configuration and bootstrapping changed after the first release

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the error "No Provider For Push" (using a local push system, not ionic cloud), where the push setup was done in a custom Provider (not directly in app.component.ts)

1. in app.module.ts (missing the provider was the cause of the error)

```
    import { Push } from '@ionic-native/push';
    ...
    providers: [
      Push,
      ...
    ]
```

2. In the Provider, initialise the push in a platform.ready() (to be sure the plugin is ready).

```
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         ...
         this.pushObject = this.push.init(options);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],

  imports: [

    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
```